# How do I use the Evil-mode gg command in info?

Tags: evil, info

Normally, thanks to the power of Evil, I can use the Vim `gg` command to go to the beginning of a buffer. When browsing `info`, however, typing `g` brings up a "Go to node: " prompt. I don't even know what this prompt means. How can I circumvent this and run my `gg`? Or is there a better way I am supposed to return to the beginning of an `info` buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply delete the <kbd>g</kbd> binding to let the evil one shine through:

```el
(define-key Info-mode-map "g" nil)
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you add more general information about problems with Evil mode in `info` (or where I can find said information)?

Comment: @RedRoboHood I'm not entirely sure what you mean. (I have a vague notion, but could you clarify?)

Comment: Basically, I was just surprised that such a basic Evil mode command was overridden by a default binding in `info` mode, and I'm looking for a list of other such cases.

Comment: @RedRoboHood `evil-motion-state` binds only keys that `Info-mode` _doesn't_ bind. If you would rather `evil-mode` override all keys, use `(evil-set-initial-state 'Info-mode 'normal)`